# Send data to observable manually

Tags: angular

I have a service which has a function. That function returns Observable. Now I don't have access to the API always. So is there a way to trigger the observable manually from service only.

```
getAll(): Observable<Demo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Demo[]>('/api/path');
}
```

Instead of above get, I want to pass hard coded SON manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `of` operator from `rxjs` module.

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

getAll(): Observable<Demo[]> {
    return of({
        your json
    });
}
```